# RStudio server suddenly not accessible anymore on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rstudio-server

I'm using AWS to host a server running RStudio Server on it.

Last week, everything was running fine when I installed all software and opened port 8787, but when I tried to access it again this week, I can't access it anymore. I restarted the server, and R Studio Server, but still no luck...

When I terminate RStudio Server, it says "rsession: no process found", maybe this tells something...

Does anyone have similar experiences with RStudio, running on AWS?

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RStudio server keeps its logs at /var/log/syslog ... did you look there to see if it is reporting anything?

Comment: This is the comment I was looking for. Thanks! In the end, turned out I forget to install one of the packages on global level.